# Nav-slider using buttons and jQuery code wont work in Safari or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I created a slider that displays different content, basically customer reviews. I used some jQuery and css to add and remove classes.  When the next or prev button is clicked the reviews change.  This code works in Chrome, but not in the other browsers.  I can't figure out why this is.  Please help.  Below I will display my HTML, CSS, and jQuery code that relates to this.

```js
var main = function() { 
"use strict";
  $('.arrow-next').click(function() {
   
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
      nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
      nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    }
    
    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
 
    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
 
  });


  $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

    if(prevSlide.length === 0) {
      prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
      prevDot = $('.dot').last();
    }
    
    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
  });

};


$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.nav-toggle {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60px;
  height: 55px;
  float: right;
}

.nav-toggle:before {
  color: #fff; /* Edit this to change the icon color */
  font: normal 28px/55px "responsivenav"; /* Edit font-size (28px) to change the icon size */
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  content: "\2261"; /* Hamburger icon */
  text-indent: 0;
  speak: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.nav-toggle.active:before {
  font-size: 24px;
  content: "\78"; /* Close icon */
}
```

```html
<section id="reviews">
      <h1 class="purple sliding-middle-out3">Reviews</h1>
      <h4 class="grey">Checkout what others are saying about Beary!</h4>
      
      <div class="wrapper2">
      <div class="slider">   
    <div class="slide active-slide">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="slide-copy ">
        <p id="quote1">
                This Studio has changed my life for the better.  Every week I am excited about going to my next dance class.  I've never had so much fun losing weight and getting into shape before!! </p>
                <h4 class="grey">- Jane S.</h4>
        </div><!--Close of slide-copy div-->
        </div><!--close of container div-->
    </div><!--close of slide div -->
    
    <div class="slide">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="slide-copy ">
 <p id="quote2">
         Thanks to Beary I got my ass off the streets and inside the studio.  I've learn to challenge my anger into something positive instead of taking it out against others.  This studio has made me a better person.  Love you Beary!</p>
            <h4 class="grey">- Terry G.</h4>
 </div><!--Close of slide-copy div-->
 </div><!--close of container div-->
</div><!--close of slide div -->

    <div class="slide">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="slide-copy ">
        <p id="quote3">
            This experience has helped me clean up my life.  I no longer feel the need to use drugs to get through the day.  Now all I think about my new dance moves and how I can't wait to learn more.  </p>
                <h4 class="grey">- Jamie R.</h4>
        </div><!--Close of slide-copy div-->
        </div><!--close of container div-->
    </div><!--close of slide div -->
    
    <div class="slide">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="slide-copy ">
 <p id="quote4">
         Beary knows how to push people to the next level.  Never before have I've gone to a place that keeps me motivated even after I leave.  I would highly recommend this dance studio to all my friends.  Its also a great place to meet new friends! </p>
            <h4 class="grey">- Jamie L.</h4>
 </div><!--Close of slide-copy div-->
 </div><!--close of container div-->
</div><!--close of slide div -->
  </div><!--close of slider div-->  
  </div><!-- end of wrapper div-->   
 <!--opening of slider review controls -->
 <div class="slider-nav">
  <button><p class="arrow-prev">Prev</p></button>
    <ul class="slider-dots">
     <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
    </ul>     
   <button><p class="arrow-next">Next</p></button>
 </div><!--closing of slider review controls -->
      
    </section>
```